# Find if there is a comma and/or digits in a String Java RegEx

Tags: java, regex

How can I find if there is a comma and/or digits in a String using Pattern and Matcher?
This String could be any length, any amount of spacing, digits commas.

I guess it should be something like this -> `"[a-zA-Z]+\\d+[,]"`
But.. It doesn't work
Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify the requirements and provide sample input and expected output. If you just check for a comma presence inside a string, use `s.contains(",")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex will math any string that have a-Z word, digits and cammas, at less on character.

```
(\w|,| )+
```

If you want to allow empty string as well. This regex will give you that.

```
(\w|,| )*
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create a character with an Hex value

```
String COMMA = "\\x2C"
```

insted a ",".

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

if you want to know what is the hex value, you can do the following:

```
int comma = ','; //Character saved in an int value.
System.out.println(comma); //this will print the decimal value
```

then you can convert to hex.

Answer (score 0):

To match any digits and/or a comma, use `[a-zA-Z,]+`